# preg_replace() everything before a match to blank only once

Tags: php

Variable value:

*1000+ lines of not required text*

**ABC:** *Required text.*

**ABC:** *More Required text.*

Goal is to replace everything before the first "ABC:" i.e the *1000+ lines of not required text* to blank. As far as I read, I need to use `preg_replace()` with the limit parameter to 1.

How do I go about doing this?

```
preg_replace("/.*/ABC:" , "ABC:", $string, 1);
```

Comment: why use a regular expression for this? You could use `strpos` to find where the first 'ABC:' is and cut the string from there.

Comment: Thanks. `echo substr($variable, strpos($variable, "ABC:"));`

Comment: Your code is almost right. The second `/` should be at the end of the string, not before `ABC`. And you need to use `.*?` so it will stop at the first `ABC:`, not the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `preg_replace()` when you can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to do this.

```
echo strstr($string, 'ABC:');
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Silly me trying to get everything complicated.

Comment: @user3027056 Happy to help :)